# Customizing how DataTables displays missing values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, missing-data, dt

`DataTables`, in Shiny, displays missing values as blank space. Is there a way to change that? I'm dreaming especially of the gray, italicized *NA*s that RStudio uses in its data viewer. I'd have no problem with injecting such strings into character columns for display purposes, but, of course, sometimes the columns are numeric, or date, and converting them just for display seems problematic.

MWE of DT's default missing values display:

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("airquality")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$airquality <- renderDataTable(airquality)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: default_dt_display]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(DT)

rowCallback <- c(
    "function(row, data){",
    "  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){",
    "    if(data[i] === null){",
    "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row).html('NA')",
    "        .css({'color': 'rgb(151,151,151)', 'font-style': 'italic'});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )

datatable(airquality, options = list(rowCallback = JS(rowCallback)))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I can see how this lets you apply any arbitrary CSS to just the missing values.

Comment: What to do to not display the rows containing NA/Missing values

Comment: This won't work if there are hidden columns, `data[I]` refer to the i-th col in the data while `'td:eq('+i+')'` refers to the i-th visible column when displaying the DT first.

Comment: Good remark @moodymudskipper. That should work however if the hidden columns are at the end.

Comment: in part. but if they are themselves NA they won't be formatted once shown.

Answer (score 3):

Customizing one of the options might be a good start:

```
options(htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS = list(na = 'string'))
```

Here's the [source](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/496) so you can read the complete thread about this issue and its workarounds.

Comment: Thanks! That is something, though, looking at `toJSON()`, it looks like it can only give us unformatted "NA"s instead of blanks.